# Ninject Binding, Interface to Interface

Tags: c#, binding, dependency-injection, ninject

I want to do something along the lines of this:

```
kernel.Bind<IBootTaskA>().To<BootTaskA>().InSingletonScope();
kernel.Bind<IBootTaskB>().To<BootTaskB>().InSingletonScope();

kernel.Bind<IBootTask>().To<IBootTaskA>();
kernel.Bind<IBootTask>().To<IBootTaskB>();
```

So i can do this:

```
public class Boot
{
     public Boot(IBootTask[] bootTasks)
     {
          foreach(var task in bootTasks){task.Execute();}
     }
}
```

but i cant seem to bind an interface to an interface, anyone know a way around this?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147996/binding-singleton-to-multiple-services-in-ninject

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10206049/ninject-is-it-possible-to-bind-different-interfaces-to-the-same-instance-of-a-c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Heres how you do it.

```
public class Service : IServiceA, IServiceB {}

this.Bind<Service>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
kernel.BindInterfaceToBinding<IServiceA, Service>();
kernel.BindInterfaceToBinding<IServiceB, Service>();
```

The ninject extention handles what you need.

https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.contextpreservation/wiki/Bind-Interface-to-Binding

**EDIT:**

In ninject 3 this is slightly easier, you no longer need contextpreservation, Simply:

```
Bind<IServiceA,IServiceB>().To<Service>().InSingletonScope();
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: [The V3 Bind overloads](http://www.planetgeek.ch/2011/12/30/new-features-and-changes-of-ninject-3-0/) address a lot of this.

---

Ninject doesnt have any constructs of that nature (and I'm not aware of other containers having such a system either).

I suspect some form of [Conditional Bindings](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding) may be most appropriate for your real problem (I assume you dont really have common marker interfaces exactly as you show).

Or are you just trying to find a construct to keep your bindings DRY? I personally would express the above as two bindings with a custom .WithStandardTaskProperties extension method rather than 4 lines.

Comment: The real problem sparking this is that I actually need to inject these in other places as well as the boot loader. That means i actually need 2 different bindings for the instance, one to get a generic list to load and then also to get an individual instance to act on. The problem is that if I bind them seperatly they will go to different singleton instances.

Comment: Have a look around - there are two answers about in this tag this year which have answers demonstrating the `Bind...` `.ToBinding` (IIRC) construct - one with an answer from @Remo Gloor (And if you're using Ninject in any way, you should go read all his top answers as your first thing anyway)

Comment: Ta for the upvote (your answer had mine from ages back) - my answer from back in the day obv wasnt much use. I've added related: links up top and there are one or two dups of the bind multiple interfaces question that need Voting to Close. This question is different enough to warrant definitely staying [and a great example of the Self-Learner badge in action!].