# Is it possible to bind different interfaces to the same instance of a class implementing all of them?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ninject, ninject-3

I have the following (simplified) situation: I have two interfaces

```
interface IAmAnInterface
{
    void DoSomething();
}
```

and

```
interface IAmAnInterfaceToo
{
    void DoSomethingElse();
}
```

and a class implementing both:

```
class IAmAnImplementation: IAmAnInterface, IAmAnInterfaceToo
{
    public IAmAnImplementation()
    {
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
    }

    public void DoSomethingElse()
    {
    }
}
```

Now I bind the same class to both interfaces using Ninject. Since I want the *same instance* of `IAmAnImplementation` beeing used for `IAmAnInterface` as well as `IAmAnInterfaceToo` it's clear that I need some kind of singleton. I played around with [ninject.extensions.namedscope](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.namedscope) as well as `InScope()` but had no success. My last try was:

```
Bind<IAmAnImplementation>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
Bind<IAmAnInterface>().To<IAmAnImplementation>().InSingletonScope();
Bind<IAmAnInterfaceToo>().To<IAmAnImplementation>().InSingletonScope();
```

But unfortunately when I request an instance of my test class via `kernel.Get<IDependOnBothInterfaces>();` it in fact uses different instances of `IAmAnImplementation`.

```
class IDependOnBothInterfaces
{
    private IAmAnInterface Dependency1 { get; set; }
    private IAmAnInterfaceToo Dependency2 { get; set; }

    public IDependOnBothInterfaces(IAmAnInterface i1, IAmAnInterfaceToo i2)
    {
        Dependency1 = i1;
        Dependency2 = i2;
    }

    public bool IUseTheSameInstances
    {
        get { return Dependency1 == Dependency2; } // returns false
    }
}
```

Is there a way tell Ninject to use the same instance of `IAmAnImplementation` for `IAmAnInterface` as well as `IAmAnInterfaceToo`?

Comment: related: See [this V2-era question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147996/binding-singleton-to-multiple-services-in-ninject) for overly detailed discussions of old invalid approaches

Answer (score 107, accepted):

It is very easy using V3.0.0

```
Bind<I1, I2, I3>().To<Impl>().InSingletonScope();
```

Comment: +1 thanks. In fact I'm using 3.0 so I'll go for this solution.

Comment: If you have more than 4 interfaces: `Bind(I1, I2, I3, I4, I5).To<Impl>().InSingletonScope();`

Comment: Can you please explain how this needs to be integrated with above scenario?

Comment: This is nice when you know all your interfaces at compile time, but not so much when you need to scan for them at runtime.

Comment: Ahh man, i had two bindings instead of multiple interfaces, which resulted in having one singleton per interface.