# Extend Ninject Bind method

Tags: c#, ninject

Ninject has [this method](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/blob/9ed842f44a8957473d50ea00ae36c0d44da2993a/src/Ninject/Syntax/BindingRoot.cs#L113).

```
public IBindingToSyntax<T1, T2, T3, T4> Bind<T1, T2, T3, T4>()
```

Is it possible somehow extend this method to bind 5 interfaces to one implementation?

Like this:

```
public IBindingToSyntax<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5> Bind<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5>()
```

Comment: is'nt it working now? did you try overloading existing parameters?

Comment: not working with five interfaces. I need bind 5 interfaces to one type. like in this [so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10206643/3373603)

Answer (score 0):

Ninject provides a fluent syntax that allows you to bind up to 4 interfaces together to the same instance:

```
Bind<IInterface1, IInterface2, IInterface3, IInterface4>().To<Implementation>();
```

If we need more interfaces there is a workaround:

```
var bindingConfiguration =
    Bind<IInterface1, IInterface2, IInterface3, IInterface4>()
        .To<Implementation>()
        .BindingConfiguration;
kernel.AddBinding(new Binding(typeof(IInterface5), bindingConfiguration));
```

Below I posted a quote from author why only four interfaces?

> Some may ask what is if I want to bind more than four interface to the
>   same service. In a small discussion we came to the conclusion that if
>   you have more than four interfaces on a single service than most
>   likely you have a problem with the single responsibility principle and
>   should fix this in first place.

Link to article [New Features and changes of Ninject 3.0](https://www.planetgeek.ch/2011/12/30/new-features-and-changes-of-ninject-3-0/)