# Bind multiple interfaces to the same implementation

Tags: c#, ninject

I have a follow up question to this question: [Is it possible to bind different interfaces to the same instance of a class implementing all of them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10206049/is-it-possible-to-bind-different-interfaces-to-the-same-instance-of-a-class-impl)

I have a scenario where one of the interface needs to be resolved by the name provided by "Named" extension, and another doesn't need a name to be resolved.

For instance

```
public interface IMachine { }
public interface IDrillMachine : IMachine { }

public class Drill: IDrillMachine { }
public class ScrewDriver: IMachine { }
```

**Ninject Binding**

```
Bind<IMachine, IDrillMachine>().To<Drill>().Named("Drill");
Bind<IMachine>.To<ScrewDriver>().Named("ScrewDriver");
```

**Injection**

```
public class MachineConsumer
{
    public MachineConsumer([Named("Drill")]IMachine drillMachine)
    { }
}

public class DrillConsumer
{
    public DrillConsumer(IDrillMachine drillMachine)
    { }
}
```

My code isn't in working condition, so can't test. But I think that at the time of resolving `IDrillMachine` there will be confusion, isn't it?

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but after looking at the linked question's accepted answer, it looks like you are missing a call to `.InSingletonScope()` in your Ninject bindings.

Comment: The only difference adding `.InSingletonScope()` would make is that I will get a single instance, instead of a new instance of `DrillMachine`. The original problem still stays, i.e. will Ninject be able to resolve `IDrillMachine` and give me an instance of `DrillMachine`?

Answer (score 1):

That won't work because the `DrillConsumer` constructor is missing the `[Named("Drill")]` name specification but the binding for `IDrillMachine` requires it.
Your scenario can be resolved by two separate bindings for `Drill`:

```
Bind<IMachine>().To<Drill>().Named("Drill");
Bind<IDrillMachine>().To<Drill>();
```

It get's a bit more complicated if `Drill` needs to be a scope object like a singleton. Adding in `InSingletonScope()` to both bindings will result in two instances, a singleton for `IMachine`("Drill") and one for `IDrillMachine`.

To resolve this you can add a level of indirection:

```
Bind<IMachine>().ToMethod(ctx => ctx.Kernel.Get<Drill>()).Named("Drill");
Bind<IDrillMachine>().ToMethod(ctx => ctx.Kernel.Get<Drill>());
Bind<Drill>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. To my surprise DrillConsumer got instantiated just fine, and didn't need `[Named("Drill")]` spec to it.