# Binding one class to several interfaces as singleton

Tags: c#, binding, dependency-injection, singleton, ninject

I have for instance 2 interfases `IInterface1` and `IInterface2`,

```
public interface IInterface1 {...}
public interface IInterface2 {...}
```

and one implementation of these interfaces `ImplClass`.

```
public class ImplClass : IInterface1, IInterface2 {...}
```

I have to be sure that application has only one instance of ImplClass, which will be used as IInterface1 and IInterface2.
I'm using ninject for dependency injection. So my qustion is: Does code below will meet my requirements?

```
...
Bind<IInterface1>().To<ImplClass>().Using<SingletonBehavior>();
Bind<IInterface2>().To<ImplClass>().Using<SingletonBehavior>();
...
```

Or this code will create 2 instances of ImplClass, for eash interface?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147996/binding-singleton-to-multiple-services-in-ninject

Comment: @Pete can you actually vote to close (good call BTW)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With Ninject you can do this:

```
var impl = new Impl();
container.Bind<IInt1>().ToMethod(c => impl);
container.Bind<IInt2>().ToMethod(c => impl);
```

When the `Impl` class has dependencies you can't Ninject to inject, you can do this:

```
container.Bind<Impl>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
container.Bind<IInt1>().ToMethod(c => c.Kernel.Get<Impl>());
container.Bind<IInt2>().ToMethod(c => c.Kernel.Get<Impl>());
```

Nice and clean.

Comment: I like it. You don't have to set up the class as an actual singleton, but you guarantee only one instance is ever provided.

Comment: -1 Not a good general solution as each resolution leads to an Activation, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043441/prevent-ninject-from-calling-initialize-multiple-times-when-binding-to-several-i

Comment: (Better answer until this duplicate question goes away is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10206049/ninject-is-it-possible-to-bind-different-interfaces-to-the-same-instance-of-a-c )

Comment: See Daan's answer below - Ninject v3 now gives you a more elegant way to do this :)

Answer (score 5):

It seems that you're still using Ninject 1.5. I havn't the exact syntax in mind anymore but it should be similat to the following 2.1 syntax:

```
kernel.Bind<I1>().ToMethod(ctx => ctx.Kernel.Get<Impl>());
kernel.Bind<I2>().ToMethod(ctx => ctx.Kernel.Get<Impl>()); 
kernel.Bind<Impl>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
```

Or even better use Ninject.Extensions.ContextPreservation to keep the context.

```
kernel.Bind<Impl>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
kernel.BindInterfaceToBinding<I1, Impl>();
kernel.BindInterfaceToBinding<I2, Impl>();
```

Comment: @JeffWalkerCodeRanger Please explain

Comment: Had upvoted, would like to change to downvote on basis its a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/4195510/11635 (and ha the same multiple activation issues)

Answer (score 3):

This is how you can do it in one line of code:

```
Bind<IInterface1 ,IInterface2 ,ImplClass>().To<ImplClass>().InSingletonScope();
```

https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.ContextPreservation/wiki/BindInterfaceToBinding

It requires Ninject version 3.

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect this would create two instances.

Try whether the following construct works for you:

```
public class ImplClass : IInterface1, IInterface2
{
    public static readonly ImplClass Instance = new ImplClass();
}
```

With the following binding:

```
Bind<IInterface1>().ToMethod(c => ImplClass.Instance);
Bind<IInterface2>().ToMethod(c => ImplClass.Instance);
```

Comment: Good answer, and a +1, but IMO part of the advantage of an IoC framework is that you can set up a singleton object without having to actually define the class structure as a singleton (making it easier to change your mind later, or set up a container or factory-scoped registration in a different environment). What if he simply initialized a class in the Binding class and registered it as a single-instance scope? (I don't know Ninject's capabilities that well, but Autofac would have no problem doing that).